# HttpClient SendAsync throwing System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have a .net framework 4.6.2 application that is sometimes returning the following error in calls using HttpClient:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Module "System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser", in ToString
  Module "System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders", in ReadStoreValues
  Module "System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders", in GetValuesAsStrings
  Module "System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders", in GetHeaderString
  Module "System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders", in GetHeaderStrings
  Module "System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler", in SetRequestHeaders
  Module "System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler", in CreateAndPrepareWebRequest
  Module "System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler", in SendAsync
  Module "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo", in Throw
  File "C:\...\PersonService.cs", line 180, col 21, in GetPersonAsync
```

Here is the code that makes the call:

```
public async Task<Person> GetPersonAsync(Guid personId)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"https://api.my-system.com/api/persons?id={personId}");

    request.Headers.Add("Server-Token", _authorization.GenerateToken());
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-msgpack"));

    var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        person = LZ4MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(), MessagePack.Resolvers.TypelessContractlessStandardResolver.Instance);
    }

    return null;
}
```

And calling this method:

```
var person = await _personService.GetPersonAsync(perosonId);
```

The code that generates the token:

```
public string GenerateToken()
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>()
    {
        new Claim("user", "my.user"),
    };

    if (Context.Current.SessionData.User != null && Context.Current.SessionData.User.Language != null)
    {
        var cultureClaim = new Claim("culture", Context.Current.SessionData.User.Language.Culture);
        claims.Add(cultureClaim);
    }

    var expirationTime = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);

    return GenerateToken(claims, expirationTime);
}

public string GenerateToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims, TimeSpan expirationTime)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var securityKey = GetBytes("Secret");
    var memoryKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(securityKey);

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
    {
        Issuer = "acms",
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(memoryKey, "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"),
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims)
    };

    if (expirationTime.TotalSeconds > 0)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        tokenDescriptor.Expires = now.AddSeconds(expirationTime.TotalSeconds);
    }

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    return tokenString;
}

private byte[] GetBytes(string input)
{
    var bytes = new byte[input.Length * sizeof(char)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(input.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    return bytes;
}
```

This error occurs intermittently, I've researched a lot and so far I haven't found any information that helps.

Has anyone seen this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to debug the problem?

Comment: What's `_authorization.GenerateToken()`?

Comment: Yes @KlausGütter, but I cannot reproduce the problem, it only occurs in production and is intermittent. I am catching these errors in our log.

Comment: @KlausGütter I wouldn't close as a duplicate of that Q&A, since this happens in .NET code (rather than user code).

Comment: Hi @CamiloTerevinto, it generates a jwt for authentication with this api.

Comment: Yeah, that's OK, but we need to see the code

Comment: usually when this error happens to me, its either because the data in production is different or because I have forgotten to await an async method.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I updated the question with GenerateToken code

Comment: @NathanS did you get exactly this error stack?

Comment: 1st major problem i see is both `var request` and `var response` are `IDisposable`. Wrap it with `using`. You may simply run out of sockets in case of large amount of requests. Probably adding `using` is the solution. And why are you returning `null`? `_personService.GetPersonAsync(perosonId)` must always throw `NullReferenceException` or the code pasted is incomplete. Please fix it to working copy.